# How to modify index notation in a sequential matrix products $\sum_{i j k} A_{j r} B_{r k} A_{i k}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, index-notation

I to write the index notation correctly in matrix/tensor product.

For example, I found notes that:

$$\sum_{i j k r p q} A_{j r} B_{r k} A_{i k} A_{i p} C_{p q} A_{j q} u_{j q}$$

By switching index $i \Leftrightarrow j, p \Leftrightarrow q, r \Leftrightarrow k$, we have

$$\sum_{i j k r p q} A_{j r} B_{r k} A_{i k} A_{i p} C_{p q} A_{j q} u_{j q} = \sum_{i j k r p q} A_{i k} B_{k r} A_{j r} A_{j q} C_{q p} A_{i p} u_{i p}$$

My question is how to know this switching index is correct. Any Principle?

---

For example, for the following equation:

$$\sum_{i j k} A_{j r} B_{r k} A_{i k}$$

Is it legal to swith $i \Leftrightarrow j$ and obtain the following:

$$\sum_{i j k} A_{j r} B_{r k} A_{i k} = \sum_{i j k} A_{i r} B_{r k} A_{j k} $$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the indices does not bear any meaning, you can change them at will,

$$
\sum_{i}A_i = \sum_{} A_{} = \sum_{j}A_j
$$

This being, there are some rules you should follow, e.g. in the example below you are not allowed to make the change $\color{blue}{i}\to \color{red}{j}$

$$
\sum_{\color{blue}{i}j} A_{\color{blue}{i}j} \not=\sum_{\color{red}{j}j} A_{\color{red}{j}j}
$$

but you can do something like

$$
\sum_{ij} A_{ij} \stackrel{i\to k}{=} \sum_{kj} A_{kj}
\stackrel{j\to i}{=} \sum_{ki} A_{ki}
\stackrel{k\to j}{=} \sum_{ji} A_{ji}
$$

which ultimately is the result of changing $i\leftrightarrow j$

Comment: Thanks for the note. The equations switch $i \Leftrightarrow j, p \Leftrightarrow q, r \Leftrightarrow k$ at the same time. Can we only switch $i \Leftrightarrow j$?  I'm curious how to write a correct form.

Comment: @jason Does the new edit give you more information?

Comment: @yes, Is there any rules for indexing when in the terms of matrix product?